# Issue with objective C outputstream flushing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tcp, flush, outputstream

Hello I'm having an issue with an NSOutputStream in Objective C. I've got a server running up on my computer and the iPhone emulator sends data to the server and the server should send it back. The only issue is, when I send it, It's not sending the text until I exit out of the Emulator, and only then does the server get the information.

```
NSString* toSend = chatField.text;
NSData* sendData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[toSend dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outStream write:[sendData bytes] maxLength:[sendData length]];
[chatField setText:@""];
```

I initialized it with

```
CFReadStreamRef reader;
CFWriteStreamRef writer;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ipField.text, 5000, &reader, &writer);
inStream = (NSInputStream *)reader;
outStream = (NSOutputStream *)writer;
[inStream setDelegate:self];
[outStream setDelegate:self];
[inStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inStream open];
[outStream open];
```

It seems to me like I'm missing something akin to the Java .flush() method. Does anyone know the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating/initializing your stream?

Comment: I edited it ^ and included the creation/initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the message you are sending to the server add "\r\n":

```
NSString* toSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", chatField.text];
```