# iOS socket How to send message to server

Tags: ios, sockets, client

I created an application using sockets, I connect to server using the code below:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.10.121", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

And I try to send a message to the server using the code below:

```
NSString *stringName  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, send message to server", userName];

// Encode
NSData *dataTake2 =[stringName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Convert to Base64 data
NSData *base64Data = [dataTake2 base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];


[outputStream write:[base64Data bytes] maxLength:[base64Data length]];
```

But it's not successful.

Comment: Check the return value of `[NSOutputStream write:maxLength]`. Please elaborate on what is not successful.

Comment: I Connected to server successfuly, but when I send a test message, nothing happen.

Comment: The only answer to your original question is :( because you don't specify what does not work.

Comment: To your comment (that clarifies it a little) - try flushing the out stream. If the message is short it may not be transmitted until the buffer is full or flushed.

Comment: Are you sending a message to a web server ?

Comment: @GermannArlington: please explain clearly, Im not good at English

Comment: @KudoCC :no, I'm try to send message to server running in an Android Device. I've connected to it, but sent message failed!

Comment: Try to check if [base64Data length] is 0 and please tell me the result of the method `[outputStream write:[base64Data bytes] maxLength:[base64Data length]];`

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695202/issue-with-objective-c-outputstream-flushing

Comment: @KudoCC When I log: NSLog(@"base64data length: %i", [base64Data length]); , the result is 44 with stringName = "tunghd:has connected.:Connect\r\n". 
Writes the contents of a provided data buffer to the receiver.
- (NSInteger)write:(const uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)length
Parameters
buffer
The data to write.
length
The length of the data buffer, in bytes.
Return Value
The number of bytes actually written, or -1 if an error occurs. More information about the error can be obtained with streamError. If the receiver is a fixed-length stream and has reached its capacity, 0 is returned.